# not able to "UPDATE SET WHERE" when I have to order with "order by case when

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-order-by, case

I have the following query which works fine (see other post from me).

```
SELECT sys_annot from ( 
         SELECT SYS_ANNOT, row_number() over (order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end) as rn
         FROM  BILL
         WHERE BIMA_TRACKING_ID = 10
         AND   BSCO_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
         AND   PARTITION_KEY = '06-DEC-17'
         AND   SUBPARTITION_KEY = 84
         AND
        (
          (  PREP_SEQ_NUM = 0
             AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID=1
             AND PRIMARY_IND=0
             AND CHRG_ACCT_ID = 1
             AND SYS_ANNOT <> 0
          )
        OR

          ( PREP_SEQ_NUM <> 0 
            AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID in ('5', '-100') 
            AND PRIMARY_IND=1
          )
        )
        )
        where rn=1
     ;
```

At the same time I want now to update the sys_annot field with the value 100 only in the single row returned by above query, that is:

```
update BILL SET SYS_ANNOT=100
where ????
```

Whatever I try it does not work, your kind help here.
Thanks

Comment: Oracle *(in my personal opinion)* makes this harder than it needs to be.

Other dialects allow `UPDATE x SET y = x FROM <some sub_query>` in various guises.  The only answers that I know of either involve temporary holding tables, or *(as now present in an answer below)* using something like `target_table.primary_key IN (some sub query)`.

Comment: Also, when you say `whatever I try`, please show what you've actually tried.  When you say `does not work`, please be specific: error message (include the error message), unexpected results (show the results you got, and the results you expected).

Answer (score 2):

You should use Primary key to identify unique record of row. You can use rowid in such case (Only works with Oracle). It wouldn't be very efficient for multiple rows, but for one row it would be good enough:

```
update BILL b SET SYS_ANNOT=100
where b.rowid in (
SELECT rid from ( 
         SELECT bill.rowid rid, SYS_ANNOT, row_number() over (order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end) as rn
         FROM  BILL
         WHERE BIMA_TRACKING_ID = 10
         AND   BSCO_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
         AND   PARTITION_KEY = '06-DEC-17'
         AND   SUBPARTITION_KEY = 84
         AND
        (
          (  PREP_SEQ_NUM = 0
             AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID=1
             AND PRIMARY_IND=0
             AND CHRG_ACCT_ID = 1
             AND SYS_ANNOT <> 0
          )
        OR

          ( PREP_SEQ_NUM <> 0 
            AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID in ('5', '-100') 
            AND PRIMARY_IND=1
          )
        )
        )
        where rn=1);
```

you can use **=** instead of **in** if you are sure that only one row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but shouldn´t you be able to nest another statement?

What I mean is you could add `update BILL SET SYS_ANNOT=100
where ????` to the begining, like:

```
update BILL SET SYS_ANNOT=100
where SYS_ANNOT = (SELECT sys_annot from ( 
         SELECT SYS_ANNOT, row_number() over (order by case when prep_seq_num = 0 then 1 else 2 end) as rn
         FROM  BILL
         WHERE BIMA_TRACKING_ID = 10
         AND   BSCO_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
         AND   PARTITION_KEY = '06-DEC-17'
         AND   SUBPARTITION_KEY = 84
         AND
        (
          (  PREP_SEQ_NUM = 0
             AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID=1
             AND PRIMARY_IND=0
             AND CHRG_ACCT_ID = 1
             AND SYS_ANNOT <> 0
          )
        OR

          ( PREP_SEQ_NUM <> 0 
            AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID in ('5', '-100') 
            AND PRIMARY_IND=1
          )
        )
        )
        where rn=1
     );
```

Comment: This query could update multiple records, while OP needs just one.